# CrashLoopBackOff on postgresql bitnami helm chart

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I know there have been already a lot of questions about this, and I read already most of them, but my problem does not seem to fit them.

I am running a postgresql from bitnami using a helm chart as described below. A clean setup is no problem and everything starts fine. But after some time, until now I could not find any pattern, the pod goes into CrashLoopBackOff and I cannot recover it whatever I try!

Helm uninstall/install does not fix the problem. The PVs seem to be the problem, but I do not know why. *And* I do not get any error message, which is the weird and scary part of it.

I use a minikube to run the k8s and helm v3.

- Helm chart: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql/10.9.5

Here are the definitions and logs:

```
# Source: aposphere/charts/sessiondb/templates/svc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sessiondb
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: sessiondb
    helm.sh/chart: sessiondb-10.9.6
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: asdf
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: tcp-postgresql
      port: 5432
      targetPort: tcp-postgresql
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: sessiondb
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: asdf
    role: primary
---
# Source: aposphere/charts/sessiondb/templates/statefulset.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: sessiondb
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: sessiondb
    helm.sh/chart: sessiondb-10.9.6
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: asdf
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
  annotations:
  namespace: default
spec:
  serviceName: sessiondb-headless
  replicas: 1
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: sessiondb
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: asdf
      role: primary
  template:
    metadata:
      name: sessiondb
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: sessiondb
        helm.sh/chart: sessiondb-10.9.6
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: asdf
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        role: primary
        app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
    spec:      
      affinity:
        podAffinity:
          
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app.kubernetes.io/name: sessiondb
                    app.kubernetes.io/instance: asdf
                    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
                namespaces:
                  - "default"
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
              weight: 1
        nodeAffinity:
          
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      automountServiceAccountToken: false
      containers:
        - name: sessiondb
          image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.13.0-debian-10-r33
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 256Mi
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1001
          env:
            - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
              value: "false"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_PORT_NUMBER
              value: "5432"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_VOLUME_DIR
              value: "/bitnami/postgresql"
            - name: PGDATA
              value: "/bitnami/postgresql/data"
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: "postgres"
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgresql-root-password
                  key: postgresql-password
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: "session"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_LDAP
              value: "no"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_TLS
              value: "no"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_LOG_HOSTNAME
              value: "false"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_LOG_CONNECTIONS
              value: "false"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_LOG_DISCONNECTIONS
              value: "false"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_PGAUDIT_LOG_CATALOG
              value: "off"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES
              value: "error"
            - name: POSTGRESQL_SHARED_PRELOAD_LIBRARIES
              value: "pgaudit"
          ports:
            - name: tcp-postgresql
              containerPort: 5432
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -d "dbname=session" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 6
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - -e
                - |
                  exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -d "dbname=session" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
                  [ -f /opt/bitnami/postgresql/tmp/.initialized ] || [ -f /bitnami/postgresql/.initialized ]
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 6
          volumeMounts:
            - name: custom-init-scripts
              mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
            - name: dshm
              mountPath: /dev/shm
            - name: data
              mountPath: /bitnami/postgresql
              subPath: 
      volumes:
        - name: custom-init-scripts
          configMap:
            name: sessiondb-scheme
        - name: dshm
          emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - "ReadWriteOnce"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: "8Gi"
```

Logs of the container:

```
% kubectl logs sessiondb-0
postgresql 10:09:01.48 
postgresql 10:09:01.48 Welcome to the Bitnami postgresql container
postgresql 10:09:01.49 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql
postgresql 10:09:01.49 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/issues
postgresql 10:09:01.49 
postgresql 10:09:01.50 DEBUG ==> Configuring libnss_wrapper...
postgresql 10:09:01.51 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
postgresql 10:09:01.54 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
postgresql 10:09:01.55 INFO  ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
postgresql 10:09:01.55 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
postgresql 10:09:01.56 DEBUG ==> Ensuring expected directories/files exist...
postgresql 10:09:01.57 INFO  ==> pg_hba.conf file not detected. Generating it...
postgresql 10:09:01.58 INFO  ==> Generating local authentication configuration
postgresql 10:09:01.58 INFO  ==> Deploying PostgreSQL with persisted data...
postgresql 10:09:01.60 INFO  ==> Configuring replication parameters
postgresql 10:09:01.65 INFO  ==> Configuring fsync
postgresql 10:09:01.71 INFO  ==> Loading custom scripts...
postgresql 10:09:01.72 INFO  ==> Loading user's custom files from /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d ...
postgresql 10:09:01.72 INFO  ==> Starting PostgreSQL in background...
pg_ctl: directory "/bitnami/postgresql/data" is not a database cluster directory
```

*Afterwards the container terminates, no more logs!*

Logs of the init container:

```
% kubectl logs sessiondb-0 init-chmod-data
+ chown 1001:1001 /bitnami/postgresql
+ mkdir -p /bitnami/postgresql/data
+ chmod 700 /bitnami/postgresql/data
+ find /bitnami/postgresql -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -name conf -not -name .snapshot -not -name lost+found
+ xargs chown -R 1001:1001
+ chmod -R 777 /dev/shm
```

Permissions:

```
I have no name!@sessiondb-0:/$ stat /bitnami/postgresql/data
  File: /bitnami/postgresql/data
  Size: 207         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 10301h/66305d   Inode: 712929      Links: 12
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1001/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1001/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2021-11-10 15:16:13.958633094 +0000
Modify: 2021-11-26 08:40:42.621884636 +0000
Change: 2021-11-26 10:37:47.844490933 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Describe the resources:

```
Name:         sessiondb-0
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-10-0-1-112.eu-central-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.112
Start Time:   Fri, 26 Nov 2021 10:40:02 +0100
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=primary
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=asdf
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              app.kubernetes.io/name=sessiondb
              controller-revision-hash=sessiondb-578ddf476b
              helm.sh/chart=sessiondb-10.9.6
              role=primary
              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=sessiondb-0
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.4
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.4
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/sessiondb
Containers:
  sessiondb:
    Container ID:   docker://a94f894687f0813196a94afe88f64723f238eb7d2cb061e4c7ef17354f27dee8
    Image:          docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.13.0-debian-10-r33
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://bitnami/postgresql@sha256:205e1c5a1d4b56d0d63f6579557652f958e321006c4cb5325d031d40313e4ea2
    Port:           5432/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 26 Nov 2021 10:50:45 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 26 Nov 2021 10:50:46 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  7
    Requests:
      cpu:      250m
      memory:   256Mi
    Liveness:   exec [/bin/sh -c exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -d "dbname=session" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:  exec [/bin/sh -c -e exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -d "dbname=session" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
[ -f /opt/bitnami/postgresql/tmp/.initialized ] || [ -f /bitnami/postgresql/.initialized ]
] delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      BITNAMI_DEBUG:                        false
      POSTGRESQL_PORT_NUMBER:               5432
      POSTGRESQL_VOLUME_DIR:                /bitnami/postgresql
      PGDATA:                               /bitnami/postgresql/data
      POSTGRES_USER:                        postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:                    <set to the key 'postgresql-password' in secret 'postgresql-root-password'>  Optional: false
      POSTGRES_DB:                          session
      POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_LDAP:               no
      POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_TLS:                no
      POSTGRESQL_LOG_HOSTNAME:              false
      POSTGRESQL_LOG_CONNECTIONS:           false
      POSTGRESQL_LOG_DISCONNECTIONS:        false
      POSTGRESQL_PGAUDIT_LOG_CATALOG:       off
      POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES:       error
      POSTGRESQL_SHARED_PRELOAD_LIBRARIES:  pgaudit
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/postgresql from data (rw)
      /dev/shm from dshm (rw)
      /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ from custom-init-scripts (rw)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data-sessiondb-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  custom-init-scripts:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      sessiondb-scheme
    Optional:  false
  dshm:
    Type:        EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:      Memory
    SizeLimit:   <unset>
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  11m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/sessiondb-0 to ip-10-0-1-112.eu-central-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Created    11m (x4 over 11m)    kubelet            Created container sessiondb
  Normal   Started    11m (x4 over 11m)    kubelet            Started container sessiondb
  Normal   Pulled     10m (x5 over 11m)    kubelet            Container image "docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.13.0-debian-10-r33" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    110s (x57 over 11m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container

---

% kubectl describe pvc data-sessiondb-0
Name:          data-sessiondb-0
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  standard
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-6b56b20c-3e56-4a92-9278-794bf6cda4de
Labels:        app.kubernetes.io/instance=asdf
               app.kubernetes.io/name=sessiondb
               role=primary
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      8Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       sessiondb-0
Events:        <none>

---

% kubectl describe pvc data-sessiondb-0
Name:          data-sessiondb-0
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  standard
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-6b56b20c-3e56-4a92-9278-794bf6cda4de
Labels:        app.kubernetes.io/instance=asdf
               app.kubernetes.io/name=sessiondb
               role=primary
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      8Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       sessiondb-0
Events:        <none>
cyrill@CyrillsMBP4380 core % kubectl describe pv pvc-6b56b20c-3e56-4a92-9278-794bf6cda4de
Name:            pvc-6b56b20c-3e56-4a92-9278-794bf6cda4de
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     hostPathProvisionerIdentity: 10bfa079-1086-4a77-849e-7d00de8e34dc
                 pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    standard
Status:          Bound
Claim:           default/data-sessiondb-0
Reclaim Policy:  Delete
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        8Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /tmp/hostpath-provisioner/default/data-sessiondb-0
    HostPathType:  
Events:            <none>
```

EDIT: Add logs with DEBUG level
--> Looking to fix: `directory "/bitnami/postgresql/data" is not a database cluster directory`

EDIT2: Add logs of the init container `volumePermissions.enabled` and permissions

EDIT3: Ok, so I created a fresh version to compare the old and the new one. I am wondering, why there is such a difference in the files as both were working until one didn't anymore. (During regular business, no upgrades, nothing.)

[image: Logs]

Comment: Can you increase the log level to "debug" maybe? Also, why tje subPath field in the last volumeMount has no value?

Comment: Added the debug logs and I get now an error message, still not so sure what it is about.

Comment: Good eye about the `subPath`, I did not see that. I used the instructions [here](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql/10.9.5#persistence) which do not mention the subpath. In the parameters, it is defaulted to "", though.

Comment: What kind of volume provisioner are you using? What kind of device is the PV (e.g. file system)? It might have to do something with the device type, file system, etc., see https://github.com/Overv/openstreetmap-tile-server/issues/94

Comment: I use the minikube standard setup: `pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath` which is essentially just a folder on the host machine

Comment: The init container isn't defined in your StatefulSet definition. Can you try setting the permission of the `/bitnami/postgresql/data` directory to 777 in the init container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239604/discussion-between-miaucl-and-weibeld).

Comment: @Miaucl Are you tight to this version? Now it's available `10.13.8` chart version. Also how often does it happen? Are there any operations performed or how can I reproduce it?

Comment: No I am not tight, I already pushed the version up to the most recent, but the same behaviour was observed.
I cannot reliably reproduce it at the moment. You can see in the image, the content of the folder for the database looks quite different and files such as `PG_VERSION` are missing. But I don't really know how that happens, when and why.
This time I was inserting some data via pgadmin and suddenly the db did not respond anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really hope nobody else runs across this, but finally I found the problem and for once it was not only between the chair and the monitor, but also RTFM was involved.

As mentioned I am using minikube to run my k8s cluster which provides PVs stored on the host disk. Where it is stored you may ask? Exaclty, here: `/tmp/hostpath-provisioner/default/data-sessiondb-0/data/`. You find the problem? No, I also took some time to figure it out. WHY ON EARTH does minikube use the `tmp` folder to store **persistant** volume claims?

[image: tmp folder]

This folder gets autom. cleared every now and so on.

SOLUTION: Change the path and DO NOT STORE PVs IN
`tmp` FOLDERS.

They mention this here: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/#a-note-on-mounts-persistence-and-minikube-hosts and give an example.

But why use the "dangerous" `tmp` path per default and not, let's say, `data` without putting a *Warning* banner there?

Sigh. Closing this question ^^

--> Workaround: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7511#issuecomment-612099413

---

Github issues to this topic:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7511
- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13038
- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3318
- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5144

My Github issue for clarification in the docs: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13038#issuecomment-981821696